# Swift 2: Call a function using an object array as a parameter

Tags: arrays, object, types, swift2, func

Here is my code:
I already have an object called "Rooms"

```
class BuildRooms  {
func build(room: [Rooms]){
    room[0].setExits([-1,-1,-1,-1])
}
```

I am trying to use it by typing:

```
var room: [Rooms] = []
BuildRooms.build(room)
```

Error occurs at BuildRooms.build(room)
It says: can not convert value of type 'Rooms' to expected argument type of 'BuildRooms'

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you tried to call function build as class / or static / function but it is declared as an instance function. I agree, that the error message which you received could be confusing, but it is correct.

```
class Rooms {}
class BuildRooms  {
    class func build(room: [Rooms]){
        print("room: \(room)")
    }
}

var room: [Rooms] = []
BuildRooms.build(room) // room: []
```

what did you do ... could be done this way

```
class Rooms {}
class BuildRooms  {
    func build(room: [Rooms]){
        print("room: \(room)")
    }
}

var room: [Rooms] = []
let br = BuildRooms()
let bf = BuildRooms.build(br) // here the parameter expected is concrete instance of BuildRooms class and returning type is ...
print(bf.dynamicType) // Array<Rooms> -> ()
bf(room) // room: []
```